# How to pass html select option value through url in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass select option value through url.selection value come from mysql table.i want to pass that driver name to another page.

```
 <?php
//another select query goes here.

$query1= "SELECT  * FROM driver WHERE status='Available'" ;
echo '<td>'.'<select name="driver">';
                        $result1= mysql_query($query1);
                        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
                                    {   
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row1["name"].'">'.$row1["name"].'</option>';    
                                    }
                                    echo '</select>'.'</td>';
echo'<a rel="facebox" href=db_confirm_booking.php?id='.$row["id"].'&driver='.$_POST['driver'].'>' . 'Confirm' . '</a>';

?>
```

Comment: And what's not working not?

Comment: It's display error "Undefined index: driver in C:\wamp\www\taxiweb\mainT\booking_management.php on line 301"

Comment: You can get driver select name after submit only or use ajax refer:http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: That means your `$_POST['driver']` isnt declared! Also you forgot quotes for the href attr. in your last echo statement. And you can't access $row outside the while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery.

Call `change` event of the drop down.

```
$(function(){
  $("[name=driver]").die('change').live('change', function(){
    var driver = $(this).val();
    if (typeof driver !== 'undefined') {
      window.location.href = 'YOUR_FILE.php?driver='+driver;
    }
  });
});
```

And

in your `YOUR_FILE.php`, get driver using `$_GET['driver']`

Or if you want the form to be more secure, take a hidden variable.

On change of `driver`, assign it the value of `driver` drop down.

And post the form.

In your PHP file, get it as `$_POST['hid_driver']`.

Answer (score 0):

U can add onclick function for the select field, try this way

```
<?php
//another select query goes here.

$query1= "SELECT  * FROM driver WHERE status='Available'" ;
echo '<td>'.'<select name="driver" onchange="window.location.href=\'db_confirm_booking.php?driver=' . $_POST['driver'] . '&id=\'+this.value">';
                        $result1= mysql_query($query1);
                        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
                                    {   
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row1["name"].'">'.$row1["name"].'</option>';    
                                    }
                                    echo '</select>'.'</td>';
echo'<a rel="facebox" href=db_confirm_booking.php?id='.$row["id"].'&driver='.$_POST['driver'].'>' . 'Confirm' . '</a>';

?>
```

Comment: same error "Undefined index: driver in C:\wamp\www\taxiweb\mainT\booking_management.php on line 301"

Comment: still same.now dispaly two errors "undefined index" in two lines.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
//another select query goes here.

$query1= "SELECT  * FROM driver WHERE status='Available'" ;
echo '<td>'.'<select name="driver" 
onChange="window.location.href=this.value">';
$result1= mysql_query($query1);
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{   
echo '<option value="db_confirm_booking.php?id='.$row["id"].'&driver='.$_POST['driver'].'">"'.$row1["name"].'">'.$row1["name"].'</option>';    
}
echo '</select>'.'</td>';
echo'<a rel="facebox" href=db_confirm_booking.php?id='.$row["id"].'&driver='.$_POST['driver'].'>
' . 'Confirm' . '</a>';

?>
```

**example code**

```
<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
<option value="www.google.com">A</option>
<option value="www.aol.com">B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: can you send me code on line number 301 in booking_management.php

Comment: echo'<a rel="facebox" href="db_confirm_booking.php?id='.$row["id"].'&driver='.$_POST['driver'].'">' . 'Confirm' . '</a>';

Comment: try this code `echo'<a rel="facebox" href="db_confirm_booking.php?id='.$row["id"]">Confirm</a>` is it working or not

Comment: yes.it's working.but i want to pass driver names also

Comment: ok try that code `<a rel="facebox" href="db_confirm_booking.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]?>&driver=<?php echo $_POST['driver'] ?>">' . 'Confirm' . '</a>';`

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="sel" id="sel" onchange="seturl(this.value)">
<option value=""></option>
</select>

<script>
function seturl(id)
{
  document.forms[0].action="test.php?driver="+id;
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
</script>
```

It will reload the page with driver name in url.